# IBM Worklight - Reliable push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use the push notification feature of Worklight, but worry about the reliability. According to the "Quality of Service" section in [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html), APNS doesn't guarantee the arrival of the message. I heard that IBM provides a MMQT mechanism for this situation, but did't find any reference from Worklight's Guides.

I also noticed that Apple doesn't allow network operations when the APP is running in the background state. So is that possible to maintain its own persistent connection and receive messages by an APP? Is there any solution to implement a reliable push notification on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Using MQ Telemetry Transport Protocol in IBM Worklight Mobile Applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/using_mq_telemetry_transport_protocol_in_ibm_worklight_mobile_applications1?lang=en)
2. Not sure I understand this one... When a Worklight application is in the background and you send a push notification the device (the OS...) will detect this and if you tap on the notification the app will then come to the foreground. If this doesn't answer your question, edit your question in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the second question, what I mean is that could the MQTT message be used as the system push notification to wake up the app from background.

Comment: The application is not supposed to automatically be brought to the foreground, I doubt this will be inalign with any vendor (Apple, Google, Microsoft,...). No push should even activate an app. An app is in the domain of the USER.

Comment: I noticed that MQTT was only developed for Android. Is there any plan to implement an iOS version for Worklight, or it's already there?

Comment: I don't know. At the bottom of the article there is a list of the authors with email address, feel free to contact them with this question.

Comment: @cao.xu did you get any answer of  this Question "Is there any plan to implement an iOS version for Worklight, or it's already there?"